# How to reference the stuct variable and intailize with or without pointer

Tags: c++, c, variables, pointers, struct

```
struct aes_key_st {
#ifdef AES_LONG
  unsigned long rd_key[4 *(AES_MAXNR + 1)];
#else
  unsigned int rd_key[4 *(AES_MAXNR + 1)];
#endif
  int rounds;
};
typedef struct aes_key_st AES_KEY;
```

The above code is stored in samp.h as struct and is assigned to AES_KEY.

In other file named samp.c i need to access the above as declared below

```
int main(void)
{
 AES_KEY enc;

}
```

The above is sample part
My question is

1. How to assign the value to enc variable.
2. How to assign the value to enc as pointer variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. However, given your code:

```
int main(void)
{
  AES_KEY  enc;
  AES_KEY *enc_ptr = &enc;  // make a pointer to enc

  enc.rounds       = 0; // Assign to the 'rounds' field of record AES_KEY
  enc_ptr->rounds  = 3; // Overwrite the 'rounds' field via a pointer


  enc.rd_key[0]      = 1 ; // Assign a value to the first element of the 'rd_key' array
  enc_ptr->rd_key[0] = 2 ; // Overwrite the same element via a pointer

}
```

Is it what you were asking?

Comment: @suuz enc_ptr->rounds is the same as (*enc_ptr).round the arrow "->" is just shorthand notation.